# c#のStatic変数はどのメモリ領域に格納されますか？

Tags: c#

c#で次のようなコード中のnumberフィールドは、どのメモリ領域に格納されるのでしょうか？

C#には静的メモリ領域はないのでしょうか
または、それ以外の領域に格納されるのでしょうか

```
Player player = new Player(); // インスタンス作成は可能

Player.number = 3; // クラス変数へアクセス可能

class Player
{
    public static int number;
}
```

Comment: この辺の記事から何か分かるかもしれませんね。[【C#文系プログラマー必見】ヒープ？スタック？メモリあれこれ](https://www.engineer-walk.com/engineer/csharp-memory/), [C#のスタックメモリとヒープメモリについて理解する](https://tech.tinybetter.com/Article/175277d5-e2b9-e132-d8ac-3a0160870d2f/View), [C# のメモリ管理](https://ufcpp.net/study/csharp/rm_gc.html), [低レベルプログラミング（No.07：スタック領域とヒープ領域）](https://atelier-yorozu.jp/?p=2769), [【C#】値型のローカル変数はどこに置かれるか](https://mslgt.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/09/30/093348)

Comment: ありがとうございます
でも、どうもstaticに関する的確なのがないような気がします
見落としているのでしょうか

Comment: 紹介した記事のうち、最初の記事の最後に図で示されている内容だと思われます。

Comment: ヒープ領域内に静的領域が含まれている図ですね

C#では、３種類のメモリ領域があるのではなく、スタック領域とヒープ領域があり、静的領域はヒープに含まれる仕組みと理解しました

Comment: 私もヒープの一部と見ています。独立して存在する派。[C#のメモリ領域](https://soft-rime.com/post-9428/), [C# メモリと値型と参照型と](https://qiita.com/YouProgramer/items/9c88045cc1c6126da354) ヒープの一部派。最初のコメントの最初の記事, [【C#】構造体(struct)やスタック領域や値型とは？](https://qiita.com/tak001/items/ae805f46e0a3ade75837), [Microsoft .NET Framework のガベージコレクション](http://uchukamen.com/Programming/GC/index.htm) 明確には言及されていない資料。[自動メモリ管理](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/automatic-memory-management), [.NET メモリ管理の概念](https://pleiades.io/help/dotmemory/NET_Memory_Management_Concepts.html), [メモリ管理](https://ufcpp.net/study/computer/MemoryManagement.html)

Comment: いろいろな情報がありますね
正解というか、実装されているわけなので何かになるのでしょうが、はっきりしないのも気持ちが悪いですね

Comment: 本家にも同じ質問があるので貼っておきます https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562199/static-class-memory-allocation-where-it-is-stored-c-sharp

Comment: ありがとうございます
リンク見ました。情報量としては一番ですね

静的変数
静的変数は、MethodTableデータ構造の重要な構成要素です。これらは、メソッドテーブルのスロット配列の直後にMethodTableの一部として割り当てられます。すべてのプリミティブ静的型はインライン化され、構造体や参照型などの静的値オブジェクトは、ハンドルテーブルで作成されたOBJECTREFを介して参照されます。MethodTableのOBJECTREFは、ヒープで作成されたオブジェクトインスタンスを参照するAppDomainハンドルテーブルのOBJECTREFを参照します。作成されると、ハンドルテーブルのOBJECTREFは、AppDomainがアンロードされるまで、ヒープ上のオブジェクトインスタンスを存続させます。

詳細な情報が多いですね
難しいですが、ざっくりした概念よりなるほど感があります

Comment: 詳細な情報が多いですね
難しいですが、ざっくりした概念よりなるほど感があります

CLRがランタイムオブジェクトを作成する方法からみることができました
この情報に辿り着けて私はよかったです

こういうのを探していました
本当にありがとうございました

Answer (score 2):

C#には参照型と値型の2種類しか存在しません。またメモリ領域はGCが管理するヒープかスタックの2種類です。

- 参照型のオブジェクトは全てヒープ上に存在し、GCによって管理されています。
- 値型は状況によって異なります。多くの場合スタックに存在しますが、記述によってはヒープ上に存在し、GCによって管理されている場合もあります。

---

> ```
> public static int number;
> ```

ということですね。構文としては [宣言ステートメント（declaration statements）](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/statements#declaration-statements) ですがその記述位置が重要です。今回のようにクラススコープの場合は[フィールド（field）](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)になります。
つまり今回の質問は静的フィールド（static field）ということになります（[静的変数](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#static-variables)とも呼ぶようですので先の回答は訂正します）。

どこ格納されるかについては、大筋としては当初の通りです。静的フィールドの型が参照型であればヒープ上でGCに管理されます。今回の例では`int`つまり値型です。この場合、このクラスを含むDLLを読み込んだ際に同時に確保されたメモリ領域であり、スタックでもヒープでもありません。

---

C# / .NETとしてはスタックとヒープという位置づけをしていますが、.NET自身は仮想環境であり、それを実現するホストプロセス、ネイティブ環境が存在します。
ネイティブ環境にもスタックとヒープが存在しますが、.NETスタックも.NETヒープもネイティブヒープに配置されるはずです。
この辺りは、.NET Runtimeがどのようにメモリに読み込みネイティブコード生成しているかに関わってきて、かなり深い知識が必要になります。実際、私もよくわかっていません。

一般的には最初に説明したように、参照型・値型の違いを把握しておけば十分かと思われます。

Comment: 質問内容を修正しました
伝わりやすくするために、サンプルコードを追加しました

Comment: staticはインスタンス毎ではなくクラスで共有されると思います
なので、インスタンス毎に確保されるエリア外に別メモリが確保されるのではと思っています。モヤモヤしますが、雰囲気で覚えるしかないのでしょうね

Comment: ローダーヒープのメソッドテーブルの最後に静的変数が格納されているのですね。英語文献で知りました。奥が深いです。確かに深い知識が必要です